# How to use a child property with a model that contains a dot

Tags: angularjs

I have two inputs that are dynamically populating a table with data per the users needs. The table rows are submitted to the controller, this is working fine. the problem is the models i need to bind them to are subjPoint.x and subjPoint.y
The angular expressions in the table are 
point.subjPointX and 
point.subjPointY
I could not get it to work with the .x
How do I set this up so the controller does not see subjPoint as a child property?
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DbmxNx72sSu42os3TCoz?p=preview)

```
//Add New POD Row
$scope.pointArray = [];
$scope.addRow = function () {
    $scope.pointArray.push({
        'subjPointX': $scope.subjPointX,
        'subjPointY': $scope.subjPointY,

    });
    $scope.subjPointX = '';
    $scope.subjPointY = '';
};
$scope.point = {};
$scope.addSubjectPoint = function () {
    var point = $scope.point;
    var index = 0;
    $scope.pointArray.forEach(function (point) {
        console.log('pointArray #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(point));
    });
    var data = JSON.stringify($scope.pointArray);
 };
```

View

```
  <form ng-submit="addSubjectPoint(point)" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <ng-form role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
    <input id="subjPointx" type="number" placeholder="Square Feet" ng-model="subjPointX" ng-pattern=" /^\d+$/" style="height: 34px;" step="500" />
      <input id="subjPointy" type="number" placeholder="Cost" ng-model="subjPointY" ng-pattern=" /^\d+$/" style="height: 34px;" step="10000"  />

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addRow()"  value=" Add"> 
  </ng-form>

  <table class="table">
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="point in pointArray">
      <td>{{point.subjPointX}}</td>
      <td>{{point.subjPointY}}</td>
       <td style="width:20px"><input type="button" value="X" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="removeRow(point.QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER)"  /></td>
  </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Update

```
              pointArray #0: {"x":500,"y":10000,"$$hashKey":"004"}
example.js:29 pointArray #1: {"x":1000,"y":20000,"$$hashKey":"006"}
example.js:29 pointArray #2: {"x":1500,"y":40000,"$$hashKey":"008"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work? [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R3wABWYJH0fOHSPEEkWK?p=preview)

**controller**

```
angular.module('demo', []);
angular.module('demo').controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
//Add New POD Row
    $scope.pointArray = [];
    $scope.addRow = function () {
        $scope.pointArray.push($scope.subjPoint);
        $scope.subjPoint = {};
    };
    //Remove  Row
    $scope.removeRow = function (x) {
        var index = $scope.pointArray.indexOf(x);
        if (index === -1) {
            alert("Something gone wrong");
        }
        $scope.pointArray.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.apply();
    };
});
```

**template**

```
<form ng-submit="addSubjectPoint(point)" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <ng-form role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
    <input id="subjPointx" type="number" placeholder="Square Feet" ng-model="subjPoint.x" ng-pattern=" /^\d+$/" style="height: 34px;" step="500" />
    <input id="subjPointy" type="number" placeholder="Cost" ng-model="subjPoint.y" ng-pattern=" /^\d+$/" style="height: 34px;" step="10000" />

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addRow()" value=" Add">
  </ng-form>

  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="point in pointArray">
        <td>{{point.x}}</td>
        <td>{{point.y}}</td>
        <td style="width:20px">
          <input type="button" value="X" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="removeRow(point)" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value=" Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: see updated post. the console needs to have { "subjPoint.x" : 500, "subjPoint.y" : 10000 }  thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do but here is a plunker, is this helpful? http://plnkr.co/edit/R3wABWYJH0fOHSPEEkWK?p=preview